How to Transfer an Android App to a New Firebase Account with the Same Package Name?
I'm moving my Android app from an old Firebase account to a new one. I've deleted the app from the old Firebase project and am trying to register it in the new Firebase account, but I keep encountering this error:

An app with this package name already exists in your project. You can register additional SHA1s for the app in Settings."


To clarify, this is a completely new Firebase account with no apps added yet. When I try to create the app using the existing package name, Firebase won’t allow it. I’ve confirmed that the app is deleted from the old project, and using a different package name does work—but I need to keep the original package name.
Is there something else I need to check or do to fully free up this package name so I can register it on the new Firebase project?
Additional context: I'm developing the app in Android Studio and using Gradle for build configuration.
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated.
Update: I was able to resolve this issue.
For anyone facing a similar problem: after permanently deleting the app from the old Firebase account, you may need to wait several hours or up to a day for the deletion to fully take effect.
Thanks to everyone who helped.

This could be because the app wasn't permanently deleted yet

"When you remove an app from your Firebase project, the app is
scheduled to be automatically permanently deleted after 30 days.
During that 30 days, you can restore the removed app before it's
permanently deleted. After the permanent deletion, though, you cannot
restore the app.
Therefore, before removing an app from your Firebase project, make
sure that permanent deletion of the app from your project is what you
really intend."
"How to immediately and permanently delete an app from a Firebase
project
If you need to immediately delete an app from a Firebase project, you
can do so anytime before Firebase automatically deletes it (which
happens 30 days after it's been removed). If you immediately delete an
app, the app will be permanently deleted and cannot be restored.
Note that you have to remove the app from your project first and then
perform an additional set of actions to delete it immediately.
Follow the instructions above to Remove an app. After removing the
app, go back to the Your apps card, and then click Apps pending
deletion. In the row for the app that you want to delete immediately,
click DELETE NOW. Confirm the changes that will occur with the
permanent deletion of the app. Click Delete app permanently."

Remove, restore, or permanently delete an app

"After removing the app, go back to the Your apps card, and then click Apps pending deletion. In the row for the app that you want to delete immediately, click DELETE NOW." I already did this.

Then wait for some time. It's possible that there might be a delay in updating the status

In the meantime try to add the app to a completely new firebase account. This will help to make sure the error isn't happening because of the particular account you're trying to migrate to
